# Parametric Time Warping in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I am working through a PTW example in R and it works well.  However when I try to substitute my own data for the data in the example, I get errors.  My data is formatted the same as the example data so I do not know what I am doing wrong.

This works:

```
data(gaschrom)
ref <- gaschrom[1:8,]
samp <- gaschrom[9:16,]
gaschrom.ptw <- ptw(ref, samp, warp.type = "individual",
optim.crit = "RMS", init.coef = c(0, 1, 0, 0))
plot(gaschrom.ptw)
plot(gaschrom.ptw, what = "signal")
```

However when I load my own data (below) it fails.  My data is 3 observations with 123 variables.  R recognizes that when I import the data into RStudio b

-13,-20.637,-19,-11,2.604,10,44,57.327,44,10,2.313,-11,-20,-6.545,1,52,70.082,57,17,18.593,0,5,4.754,4,-3,-1.204,-1,10,26.964,25,43,57.435,40,17,12.874,-2,-16,-27.441,-23,-24,-31.418,-20,-11,-13.463,-6,-3,-4.643,-2,-2,-4.643,-3,-6,7.727,10,44,53.049,40,-3,-14.796,-24,-24,-31.708,-20,-11,-14.598,-7,-7,-10.321,-7,-7,-10.321,-7,-7,6.591,10,44,57.327,44,10,7.727,-6,-3,6.056,8,30,38.152,29,5,-2.474,-11,-19,-30.548,-23,-24,-31.418,-20,-11,-14.598,-7,-7,6.591,10,44,57.327,44,10,8.388,-5,-1,-3.134,-1,-5,-12.802,-11,-20,-27.431,-20,-11,-8.966,-1,10,12.209,10
-2,7.554,-2,40,49.062,40,-3,-14.796,-24,-24,-29.912,-18,-6,18.559,24,73,93.119,69,12,23.458,3,41,51.912,41,2,-0.353,-11,1,15.803,18,41,47.903,33,-5,-12.677,-20,-11,-18.876,-11,-20,-28.646,-21,-15,-23.738,-15,-21,-25.161,-16,-1,2.826,7,7,12.736,9,14,11.417,6,-14,-24.368,-22,-19,-28.863,-19,-21,-33.117,-23,-24,-35.696,-24,-24,-26.076,-14,6,3.654,6,-14,-9.964,-8,24,28.462,24,-8,-14.461,-19,-8,-8.92,-2,-2,-7.212,-6,-13,-23.74,-19,-22,-18.166,-8,24,38.372,34,22,25.179,11,2,-2.715,-6,-13,-2.55,2,41,66.592,56,46,49.651,24,-8,-9.964,-14,6,3.654,6,-14,-20.663,-19
-19,-27.154,-17,-17,-22.032,-13,-6,-10.917,-6,-13,-22.032,-17,-17,-22.032,-13,-6,-10.917,-6,-13,-22.032,-17,-17,-22.032,-13,-6,-10.917,-6,-13,-2.702,2,41,55.285,45,13,16.614,2,11,14.481,11,2,-6.924,-10,-26,-23.842,-15,24,36.204,34,16,27.907,15,32,46.134,34,22,21.475,7,-9,-17.535,-17,-17,-22.032,-13,-6,-4.863,0,5,5.889,5,0,-4.863,-6,-13,-22.032,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-25.736,-17,-17,-6.407,2,41,50.162,39,-2,-13.788,-23

My data is 3 observations with 123 variables.  R recognizes that when I import the data into RStudio but when I try to run the analysis as follows, it does not work.

```
train <- read.csv(file="threesamps2.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",")#this works, the data is brought into "train" and shows to have 3 observations with 123 variables.

ref <- train[1,]# This works and shows 1 obs, 123 variables
samp <- train[2:3,]# This works and shows 2 obs, 123 variables
train.ptw <- ptw(ref, samp, warp.type = "individual",
          optim.crit = "RMS", init.coef = c(0, 1, 0, 0))#This seems to be what is failing.  Why?  It works fine with the sample data.
plot(train.ptw)
plot(train.ptw, what = "signal")
```

Both ref and samp load correctly but the error I get is "Error in plot(train.ptw, what = "signal") : object 'train.ptw' not found."  If I am reading the code correctly, train.ptw should be created but yet it is not found.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case your question is still open:

I think the issue is that the ptw function requires a vector if you have only one reference signal. It worked on my system (R 3.6.1 with ptw_1.9-13) when I converted `ref` to a vector:

```
train <- read.csv(file="threesamps2.csv", header=FALSE, sep=",")

ref <- as.numeric(train[1,])
samp <- train[2:3,]
train.ptw <- ptw(ref, samp, warp.type = "individual",
          optim.crit = "RMS", init.coef = c(0, 1, 0, 0))
plot(train.ptw)
```